# Kohana Query Builder: and or where clause

Tags: kohana, builder

```
            ->where('orders.date_paid', 'BETWEEN', array($from, $to))
            ->and_where('orders.status', '=', 'new')
            ->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')
```

I would like to show all rows where date_paid is between $from and $to, where status is either new or delivered.

When i add this or_where(), it ignores the BETWEEN $from and $to date_paid where clause.

How can i do this right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to group your conditions.

```
->where('orders.date_paid', 'BETWEEN', array($from, $to))
->and_where_open()
->where('orders.status', '=', 'new')
->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')
->and_where_close();
```

Comment: You could also use the `->where('order.status', 'IN', array('new', 'delivered'));`